# Regex select the inside if the outside matches

Tags: c#, .net, regex

It's tricky to find answers specific answers about regex so i'm sorry if it's a repost.

As the title says, I need to get the value of a string between brackets, if the rest of the string matches.
Specifically a hexadecimal in my case.

For example, this should output `A35` and ignore the 0.

> There are [A35] cats and 0 tigers in a tree.

But this shouldn't match at all:

> There are [A35] DOGS and 0 tigers in a tree.

So far I've got:

```
There are \[[a-fA-F0-9]+\]+ cats and 0 tigers in a tree.
```

With a second regex to get values between [].

```
\[(?s)(.*)\]
```

Which works but I doubt it's the most efficient way. Any attempts to combine these two, as well as anything else i try, seems to result in a pattern error.

Comment: `Regex.Match(s, @"There are \[([^][]+)\] cats and 0 tigers in a tree\.").Groups[1].Value`

Comment: `\w` can match any word character, which means both letters and numbers. You could use `@"\[\w+\]"` to match the tag or parentheses to group specific matches, eg `@"\[(\w+)\]"` and retrieve them through the `Groups` property , eg `match.Groups[1]`. The first group is always the entire match. You can also give a name to the group with `(?<name>...)`, `@"\[(?<num>\w+)\]"` and retrieve it by name with `Groups["num"]`

Comment: Thank you. That... explains a lot about my failed attempts.

Comment: If you want to *ignore* the second number, you can match it but not use it. The full pattern could look like this `@"There are \[(?<num>\w+)\] cats and \d+ tigers in a tree."`.

Comment: `Regex.Match(s, @"There are \[([a-fA-F0-9]+)\]+ cats and 0 tigers in a tree.").Groups[1].Value` seems to be the most efficient looking specifically for a hexadecimal value.
I had no idea about groups. That's what happens when you keep telling yourself to learn regex but never do. Then you're screwed when you need it. :P